# How to get phone number from a complex string with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I need to take count of digits if users write more **than 4 digits** into textArea.

How can I do it with regex?

```
var phone = str.search(/\d{5}/);
var mail = str.search(/\S+@@\S+\.\S+/);
if (mail > -1 || phone > -1) {
  document.getElementById("commentuyari").innerHTML = "Please don't share your contact infos !";
}else {
  document.getElementById("commentuyari").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Above the solutions is right for me. But if a user write like "583 add 434 as 44 as 33", I want to warn it. How can I do it ?

Comment: Then the users will just start writing the words `five`, `four`, `one`, `three`, `two`, `zero`, `three`, `two`, `nine`, `seven`. A simple scan for numerics will not catch that. It *will*, however, catch a lot of false positives.

Comment: I *am* trying to help by pointing out that the approach is wrong - it's very error prone and will not solve your issue.

Comment: It will solve. I wanna just warn users with alert() function. Not to forbidden them.

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to just do a regex replacement and remove all non numeric characters:

```
Find:    \D+
Replace: (empty)
```

This would leave you with the actual digits which were entered.

### Demo